# Complex MySQL query code

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

Table 1: Badge
Columns: badgeid(PrimaryKey), value

Table 2: User
Columns: userid(PrimaryKey), name

Table 3: Badge_User
Columns: userid(ForeignKey), badgeid(ForeignKey)
(One user will never have same badge twice)

I need a table so that all the badge values are summed up and displayed for each user.

For example:

```
   Table 1: Badge 
   | badgeid  value  |
   |   1      5      |
   |   2     10      | 
   |   3     15      |



   Table 2: User 
   | userid  name    |
   |   1      Bob    |
   |   2      Mike   |
   |   3      Duke   |
   |   4      Craig  |



   Table 3: User_Badge
   | userid  badgeid |
   |  1        1     |
   |  1        2     |
   |  2        3     |
   |  2        2     |
   |  2        1     |
   |  3        3     |
   |  1        1     |
```

I want the query result be like this and sorted by the highest sum_of_badge_value
Query:
userid, name, sum_of_badge_value
row1: 2, Mike, 30
row2: 1, Bob, 15
row3: 3, Duke, 15
row4: 4, Craig, 0

Any help on how to write this query would be appreciated!

Comment: **I want** SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
___Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you___

Comment: Have a look at how others have asked questions here. And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Marcipanas what you tried?

Comment: @RiggsFolly and Strawberry You almost forgot to mention that this is a homework problem.

Comment: Read / work on following links ,try to prepare query and add to question.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not complex at all and you should really try to figure this out on your own by reading some basic SQL tutorials!
I'll give you some hints.

```
SELECT ______,
       sum(_____)
FROM _____ ba_us
JOIN _____ ba USING(____id)
JOIN _____ us USING(____id)
GROUP BY _____
```

Comment: This does work but I need to show also the users that do not have any badge at all. This only shows all users which have badges. Is there a way to include users which did not match with a badge?

Comment: Replace the `Join` to the badges with a `left join` and read this:
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/